# Spline interpolation R with conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, spline

I have a very large data set, structured as the sample below.

I have been trying to use the na.spline function in order to

1) identify the "fips" category with missing Yield.

2) if less than than 3 Yield values are NA per fips (here 1-3) the spline function should kick in and fill in the NA.

3) If 3 or more Yields are NA for a "fips" the code should remove the entire "fips" subset, in this case fips 2 should be removed.

My code so far:

```
 finX <- dataset

 finxx <- transform(subset(finX, ave(na.spline(finX$Yield), fips, FUN=sum)<2))

 #or

 finxx <- transform(subset(finX, ave(is.na(finX$Yield), fips, FUN=sum)<2))

Year   fips   Max     Min   Rain  Yield
1980   1      24.7    0.0   71    37
1981   1      22.8    0.0   62    40
1982   1      22.6    0.0   47    37
1983   1      24.2    0.0   51    39
1984   1      23.8    0.0   61    47
1985   1      25.1    0.0   67    43
1980   2      24.8    0.0   72    34
1981   2      23.2    0.4   54    **NA**
1982   2      25.3    0.1   83    55
1983   2      23.0    0.0   68    **NA**
1984   2      22.4    0.7   70    **NA**
1985   2      24.6    0.0   47    31
1980   3      25.5    0.0   51    31
1981   3      25.5    0.0   51    31
1982   3      25.5    0.0   51    31
1983   3      25.5    0.0   51    **NA**
1984   3      25.5    0.0   51    31
...
```

Currently the codes above either do not fill in all the NA's in the final product, or simply have no result at all.

Any guidance would be very useful, thank you.

Comment: In cases like these it might also be worth taking a look at imputation packages like AMELIA. Since na.spline just interpolated on the Yield variable. Might be there are useful information in the other variables like Rain, Max, that are correlated with Yield and may help improving the estimation of the NA. AMELIA can use these inter-variable correlations, while univariate time series imputation methods from the zoo or imputeTS package do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Yield` needs to be converted from character to numeric or `NA`.  Then use `by` to divide `finX` into separate data frames by `fips` value. For each data frame with less than 3 `NA's`, do the spline interpolation.  Those with 3 or greater are returned as `NULL`.  Combine the `list` of returned data frames into single data frame.  Code would look like:

```
  library(zoo)
# convert finX$Yield values from character to either numeric or NA
  finX$Yield <- sapply(finX$Yield, function(x) if(x =="**NA**") NA_real_ else as.numeric(x))

# use spline interpolation on fips sets with less than 3 NA's
   finxx <- by(finX, finX$fips, function(x) if(sum(is.na(x$Yield)) < 3) transform(x, Yield=na.spline(object=Yield, x=Year)) )    
#  combine results into a single data frame
  finxx <- do.call(rbind, finxx)
```

Alternatively after the conversion to numeric values, you could use `ave` on the `Yield` column where spline interpolation returns values on `fips` sets with less than 3 NA's and all NA's on any other sets.  All rows with any NA's in the final result would then be deleted.  Code is as follows:

```
finxx2 <- transform(finX, Yield=ave(Yield, fips, FUN=function(x) if(sum(is.na(x)) < 3) na.spline(object=x) else NA))
finxx2 <- na.omit(finxx2)
```

Both versions give the same result for the sample data but the first version using `by` allows you to work with a full data frame for each `fips` set rather than with just `Yield`.  In this case, this allowed `Year` to be specified for the `x` values in the spline interpolation so any data set with a missing `Year` would still give the correct interpolation.  The `ave` version would get an incorrect answer. So the `by` version seems more robust.

There's also the `dplyr` version which is very much like the `by` version above and gives the same answer as the base R versions. If you're OK with working with `dplyr`, this is probably the most straightforward and robust approach.

```
library(dplyr)
finxx3 <- finX %>% group_by(fips) %>%
      filter(sum(is.na(Yield)) < 3) %>%
      mutate(Yield=na.spline(object=Yield, x=Year))
```

The first version returns

```
     Year fips  Max Min Rain Yield
1.1  1980    1 24.7   0   71    37
1.2  1981    1 22.8   0   62    40
1.3  1982    1 22.6   0   47    37
1.4  1983    1 24.2   0   51    39
1.5  1984    1 23.8   0   61    47
1.6  1985    1 25.1   0   67    43
3.13 1980    3 25.5   0   51    31
3.14 1981    3 25.5   0   51    31
3.15 1982    3 25.5   0   51    31
3.16 1983    3 25.5   0   51    31
3.17 1984    3 25.5   0   51    31
```